# Clicking an element on a page through Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, click

I am trying to create a chrome extension that will click on an element on a webpage when you click a button on the extension, but for some reason it does nothing no matter what I try.

I've got this so far

manifest.json

```
{  
  "manifest_version": 2,  

  "name": "Such Activity",  
  "description": "Wow",  
  "version": "1.0",    
  "permissions": [  
        "tabs", "<all_urls>"  
    ],  

  "browser_action": {  
    "default_icon": "icon.png",  
    "default_popup": "popup.html"  
  },  
     "content_scripts": [  
        {  
            "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],  
           "js": ["content_script.js"]  
            }  
        ]  
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
  <head>  
    <title>activity</title>  
    <style>  
    </style>  
    <script src="content_script.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
  <button id="clickactivity">click</button>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

content_script.js

```
function ClickPlanet()
    {
        var planets = document.getElementsByClassName("planet-name");
        var randomplanet = Math.floor(Math.random() * planets.length);
        var clickplanet = planets[randomplanet];
        clickplanet.click();
        setInterval(function () { ClickPlanet() }, 2000);
    }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', ClickPlanet);
});
```

All I seem to be getting is this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

I've been fiddling around with this for hours, but I can't get it to work. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Quoting the official documentation:

> Content scripts are JavaScript files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to them.

So, using your `content_script.js` in your `popup.html` doesn't make much sense, and results in an error because you don't have any button with `class="planet-name"` in your `popup.html` page.

To do what you want, you need to create a different script for your `popup.html`, and add a listener to that button, so when it gets clicked, you can inject the `content_script.js` script into the page to click the "planet" element.

So you'll have to:

1. Edit your `manifest.json` removing the `"content_scripts"` field.
2. Create a `popup.js` file to add in your `popup.html` page.
3. Add a listener for the button click inside `popup.js` to inject the `content_script.js` file using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-executeScript) (Manifest V2) or [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) (Manifest V3).
4. Edit your `content_script.js` to make it click the button directly on the page.

---

### Manifest V3 Solution

1. Edit your `manifest.json`, it should look like this:

   ```json
   {
       "manifest_version": 3,

       "name": "Such Activity",
       "description": "Wow",
       "version": "1.0",
       "permissions": ["scripting"],
       "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],

       "action": {
           "default_title": "Click Me",
           "default_popup": "popup.html"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then, remove your `content_script.js` from the `popup.html` and replace it with the `popup.js` script:

   ```html
   <!doctype html>  
   <html>  
       <head><title>activity</title></head>  
   <body>  
       <button id="clickactivity">click</button>  
       <script src="popup.js"></script> 
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Create the `popup.js` script and add the listener to the button that will inject the script into the current page:

   ```js
   function injectTheScript() {
       // Wuery the active tab, which will be only one tab and inject the script in it.
       chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
           chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId: tabs[0].id}, files: ['content_script.js']})
       })
   }

   document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript)
   ```
4. Now, in your `content_script.js`, you'll need to click the button directly, and also you will not need to use `DOMContentReady`, because Chrome waits to inject the script by itself. So, your new `content_script.js` will be:

   ```js
   const planets = document.getElementsByClassName("planet-name")
   const elementToClick = planets[Math.floor(Math.random() * planets.length)]
   elementToClick.click()
   ```

---

### Manifest V2 Solution (*deprecated!*)

**NOTE**: since January 2021, you should use the new [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/). See above for an up-to-date answer if you are using Manifest V3.

1. First of all, edit your `manifest.json`, it should look like this:

   ```json
   {  
       "manifest_version": 2,  

       "name": "Such Activity",  
       "description": "Wow",  
       "version": "1.0",    
       "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],  

       "browser_action": {  
           "default_icon": "icon.png",  
           "default_popup": "popup.html"  
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then, remove your `content_script.js` from the `popup.html` and replace it with the `popup.js` script:

   ```html
   <!doctype html>  
   <html>  
       <head><title>activity</title></head>  
   <body>  
       <button id="clickactivity">click</button>  
       <script src="popup.js"></script> 
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Create the `popup.js` script and add the listener to the button that will inject the script into the current page:

   ```
   function injectTheScript() {
       chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
           // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
           //and inject the script in it
           chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
       });
   }

   document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
   ```
4. Now, in your `content_script.js`, you'll need to click the button directly, and also you will not need to use `DOMContentReady`, because Chrome waits to inject the script by itself. So, your new `content_script.js` will be:

   ```
   function clickPlanet() {
       var planets = document.getElementsByClassName("planet-name"),
           randomplanet = Math.floor(Math.random() * planets.length),
           clickplanet = planets[randomplanet];

       clickplanet.click();
   }

   clickPlanet();
   ```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I understand the way you need to inject the script completely now while previously it was all just... vague. Yet, it still doesn't work. I'm not getting the error anymore but the element is not being clicked either

Comment: Then add an alert like `alert('CONTENT SCRIPT: I am running!')` in your `content_script.js`, so you can see if it gets injected correctly...

Comment: No alert. For reference, this is the website I'm trying to apply this to: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17879954/EN%20Betelgeuse.htm
The planets that need to be clicked are on the right

Comment: @RicoClark I edited the question and tested it by myself on the page you provided. Now it works, there was a little problem because using `run_at: "document_end"` in a page that has already loaded doesn't actually run anything. Reload your extension with the new code of my answer and see if it works.

Comment: @RicoClark I also added a download link to download the example if you want.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It works perfectly. I also now understand how the injection works so I'll know for the future. You're the best

Comment: Now I only have one remaining issue, when the script is executed and it clicks, the page navigates to another URL. I need the script to be persistent so it will click every 2 seconds. Also, what is the function of the background.js that you declared in the manifest?

Comment: @RicoClark oh, forget the background.js, I copied the manifest of one of my extensions, you don't need it. By the way, if you want the script to click every two seconds and the page changes you'll have to use the background, but it's a bit complicated: you should use message passing and listen to the tabs.onUpdated event to inject the script several times...

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with onUpdated. background.js: `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, info, tab){
if (tab.status !== "complete"){
        return;
    }
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {"file": "content_script.js"});
 });` 
Works perfectly with a Timeout in the content_script

Comment: This only works when the page is focused. Is there also a way to make this work when the page is not focused? (or am I doing something wrong?)