# Google extension how to click a button on the web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I create an extension
file **github.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log('github.js');
  // btn btn-primary shelf-cta
  var button = $('.btn.btn-primary.shelf-cta');
  console.log('button.html() = ', button.html());
  button.click();
});
```

file popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="send_messages">Send Messages</button>

  <script src="libs/jquery-v3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

file **popup.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log('popup.js');

  $('#send_messages').click(function(event) {


    console.log('github test');
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tabs[0].id,
        {file: "libs/jquery-v3.3.1.js"},
        function(){
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            tabs[0].id,
            {file: "github.js"}
          );
        }
      );
    });
  });
});
```

file **manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "test the extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Automatically send the message to the opened projects in the browser",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "activeTab", 
    "declarativeContent", 
    "storage",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

When I go to the github page https://github.com/
there is a button "read the guide", I want to click it.
I press an extension browser_action button, shows a pop-up window. When I press a button "send a message" and nothing happens.
I can reach the button "read the guide" and output the title but **button.click();** doesn't work.
How to click the button or others link?

Comment: Generally speaking, one would try it. If not yet successful, then one would follow the directions they found when searching for the way that others did it. Curiously enough, the following search term "click button in chrome extension" causes google to chuck me a link to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390322/clicking-an-element-on-a-page-through-chrome-extension

Comment: I checked code on your link and it works. but when I added jquery  it doesn't work

Comment: (Un?)fortunately, I have had the luxury of eschewing any projects where jQuery was mandated. As a consequence, I've not learned it nor developed any interest in it and it seems, are unable to help any further. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the click in jquery need to do by using this code

```
button.get(0).click();
```

not like I did

```
button.click();
```